# Parsing PSCustomObject in PowerShell, Eventlogs

Tags: windows, events, powershell, cut

So I am in need of some assistance. I got put on a project, involving writing a powershell script. And I need to be able to get the most recent SuccessAudit from the security log in a Windows 7 machine, ID=4776.

I managed to get this done in a couple of hours, it is my first time using powershell.

```
$eventtime=Get-EventLog Security | {$_.EventId -eq 4776} | where {$_.entrytype -eq "SuccessAudit"} | Select-Object TimeGenerated | Select -first 1
```

Output via console (w/o setting a variable):

```
TimeGenerated
--------------------------
4/10/2013 10:35:01 PM
```

If i set the command to a variable, this is the result of the variable:

```
@{TimeGenerated=4/10/2013 10:35:01 PM}
```

I would like to cut the variable so that it will only equal the date and time:
*4/10/2013 10:35:01 PM*

Help! I've been at it for hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$eventtime=Get-EventLog Security | ? {$_.EventId -eq 4776} | 
where {$_.entrytype -eq "SuccessAudit"} | 
Select-Object -expand TimeGenerated | Select -first 1
```

Comment: @CB., this worked for me, too, ty! By just doing Select-Object -Property  I got an array (Object[]) of  PSCustomObject , and by changing to use -ExpandProperty instead I got the array of items I desired.

Comment: @AnneTheAgile Good! Glad to help again ;)